# Output dataframe to indexed json in R

Tags: r

I would like to output a dataframe to JSON indexed by one of its columns as an ID.
The purpose is that when the JSON will get converted by php it would result in an associative array with the ID as the index. How can I do that?

```
library(jsonlite,dplyr)
df <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = 'id') %>% 
  select(id,mpg,cyl) %>%
  head(5)

toJSON(df)
```

Outputs this:

```
[
{"id":"Mazda RX4","mpg":21,"cyl":6},
{"id":"Mazda RX4 Wag","mpg":21,"cyl":6},
{"id":"Datsun 710","mpg":22.8,"cyl":4},
{"id":"Hornet 4 Drive","mpg":21.4,"cyl":6},
{"id":"Hornet Sportabout","mpg":18.7,"cyl":8}
]
```

What should I do with df to get this?

```
{
    "Mazda RX4": {
        "mpg": 21,
        "cyl": 6
    },
    "Mazda RX4 Wag": {
        "mpg": 21,
        "cyl": 6
    },
    "Datsun 710": {
        "mpg": 22.8,
        "cyl": 4
    },
    "Hornet 4 Drive": {
        "mpg": 21.4,
        "cyl": 6
    },
    "Hornet Sportabout": {
        "mpg": 18.7,
        "cyl": 8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will provide the correct `json` format needed.

You can `nest` the columns of data without `id`, and use `id` with `setNames` to get the desired format.

The `lapply` with `unbox` will remove the brackets.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = 'id') %>% 
  select(id, mpg, cyl) %>%
  head(5) %>%
  nest(data = -id) %>%
  { setNames(.$data, .$id) }
  
toJSON(lapply(df, unbox), pretty = TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
{
  "Mazda RX4": {
      "mpg": 21,
      "cyl": 6
    },
  "Mazda RX4 Wag": {
      "mpg": 21,
      "cyl": 6
    },
  "Datsun 710": {
      "mpg": 22.8,
      "cyl": 4
    },
  "Hornet 4 Drive": {
      "mpg": 21.4,
      "cyl": 6
    },
  "Hornet Sportabout": {
      "mpg": 18.7,
      "cyl": 8
    }
}
```

Comment: Piping into lapply like this %>% lapply(. %>% unbox) makes it a bit easier to handle for me.